# Produce Long Kafka Header with Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-kafka, header, apache-camel, spring-camel

In my Springboot Camel application I'm using the Kafka integration to produce message on a topic.
I compared message produced by Camel Kafka integration with message produced by Kafka Spring integration and I noticed one little difference:
in OffsetExplorer, messages produced by Spring Kafka uses an Header "spring_json_header_types" with the class of all other headers, and header Long or Integer are correctly showed and serialized.
With Camel instead, if I set an header not String, in OffsetExplorer it is represented with the square char.
I did my research and found that Spring Kafka uses the DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper to create this header, and this help the inbound process to know how to deserialize the other header.
How can I use it in my Camel Kafka Producer?
Here my code:

```
@Component
public class KafkaProducerRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {        
        from("timer:myTimer?period=10000")
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("TIMER_COUNTER_1", exchange.getProperty(Exchange.TIMER_COUNTER, Long.class));
                headers.put("TIMER_COUNTER_2", String.valueOf(exchange.getProperty(Exchange.TIMER_COUNTER, Long.class)));
                exchange.getIn().setHeaders(headers);
            }
        })
        .to("kafka:topic1?brokers=localhost:9092");
    }
}
```

Comment: What Camel version do you use? And can you point out what is the fully classname for that `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper` you talk about?

Comment: Camel is the dependency: camel-spring-boot-starter version 3.20.2.
The class for the header instead is org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.
I think the header spring_json_header_types is somehow generated using this class

Comment: Okay so I assume its spring specific with that header - its metadata that they send along, so if you use spring on the "other side" then it can know what types the headers are. (Kafka seems to lack such metdata out of the box)

Comment: Yes, I think in kafka the headers format is always an array of byte.

Comment: I created a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-19215